# Unzip files in C# (using winzip command line)

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, winzip

I'm trying to create program to unzip files. I need to use winzip command line. I try to send in argument command to cmd, but it didn't work, because cmd didn't know my command. When I pasted manually command, it works.

```
var process = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
var command = "/c WZUNZIP -spassword" + "\""+ "C:\my path\file.zip" + "\"" + " " + "\"" + "C:\my path" + "\"";
process.UseShellExecute = false;
process.Arguments = command;
Process.Start(process);
```

I tried to create .bat file and execute this file in my program, but like before it didn't work, when I executed it in my program and when start manually it works.

```
start cmd.exe /c WZUNZIP -spassword "C:\my path\file.zip" "C:\my path"
var process = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", pathToBatch);
Process.Start(process);
```

Mayby u know, the best way to execute .bat file in C#.

I need to use winzip, because only it provides encoding for my files. I tried to use DotNetZip and during uziping program threw exception that it can't be unziped, because library can't operate this files.

Comment: Can you use `System.IO.Compression`? It just seems like that might be easier.

Comment: Also, if not, can you show us the code you *are* using to start the file? It seems like that's more relevant here even than the contents of the batch file itself.

Comment: `UseShellExecute = false` - I think that needs to be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes go aroundthe entire path incl drive letter `"c:\some folder\some file.zip"`

---

To unzip

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set DestFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(1))
Set SrcFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(0))
Set FldrItems=SrcFldr.Items
DestFldr.CopyHere FldrItems, &H214
Msgbox "Finished"
```

and to zip

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set SrcFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(1))
Set DestFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(0))
Set FldrItems=SrcFldr.Items
DestFldr.CopyHere FldrItems, &H214
Msgbox "Finished"
```

and create a blank zip.

```
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(Ag(0), 8, vbtrue)
BlankZip = "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6)
For x = 0 to 17
    BlankZip = BlankZip & Chr(0)
Next
ts.Write BlankZip
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for adding as an answer (I currrently don't have enough rep for posting comments), but hopefully this will help.

What is the reason that you need to use winzip command line? Could you use ionic zip instead (http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/ - also obtainable via NuGet in Visual Studio). I've used it a few times to zip files up and I know it unzips just as well.

The benefit I can see of not using the winzip command line is that you don't get the command prompt window popping up onscreen while the unzip is in progress.

Otherwise, as Noodles has suggested, the quotes must go around the whole path, not just the folders containing the spaces.

Edit: There is a similar SO post here: [unzip file in C# via Winzip and its cmd extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432893/unzip-file-in-c-sharp-via-winzip-and-its-cmd-extension)

Comment: Ok, no problem. I see you updated your original post with the reasons why you must use WinZip. I'll take a look into it further this evening if it isn't fixed in the interim.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute any thing you can use the **process class** with **ProcessStartInfo.Arguments**.

You can see more at:

- [MSDN: Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Process(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MSDN: ProccessStartInfo.Arguments Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx)

And my question is because I don't understand for what you want it,
why don't you use **system.IO.Compression** or **SharpzipLib**? You can look up more info and download it with nugget.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", @"/c  WZUNZIP.EXE -ye -o " + zipPath + " " + ExtractedFilesLocation);
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();
            proc.WaitForExit();
```